# OpenAL with 64bit architecture on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, openal

When I run my previous game against the 64 bit architecture, I get OpenAL errors..

It says "no matching function for call to alGenBuffers" and "no matching function for call to alGenSources". How can I fix these errors?

The whole method

```
-(bool) loadSoundWithKey:(NSString *)_soundKey File:(NSString *)_file Ext:(NSString *) _ext Loop:(bool)loops{


        ALvoid * outData;
        ALenum  error = AL_NO_ERROR;
        ALenum  format;
        ALsizei size;
        ALsizei freq;

        NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

        CFURLRef fileURL = (__bridge_retained CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundle pathForResource:_file ofType:_ext]];

        if (!fileURL)
        {
            NSLog(@"file not found.");
            return false;
        }

        outData = GameGetOpenALAudioData(fileURL, &size, &format, &freq);

        CFRelease(fileURL);

        if((error = alGetError()) != AL_NO_ERROR) {
            printf("error loading sound: %xn", error);
            exit(1);
        }

        NSUInteger bufferID;
        alGenBuffers(1, &bufferID); // error

        alBufferData(bufferID,format,outData,size,freq);

        [bufferStorageArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:bufferID]];

        NSUInteger sourceID;
        alGenSources(1, &sourceID); // error

        alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, bufferID);

        alSourcef(sourceID, AL_PITCH, 1.0f);
        alSourcef(sourceID, AL_GAIN, 1.0f);
        if (loops) alSourcei(sourceID, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);


        if (outData)
        {
            free(outData);
            outData = NULL;
        }


        return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the default OpenAL.framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out..

Apparently `alGenBuffers` and `alGenSources` require `GLuint` not `NSUInteger`!